# Windows Live Messenger losing messages?

Tags: instant-messaging, windows-live-messenger

We recently upgraded to Live Messenger 2009 (build 14.0.8089.726) and users have started losing messages.  The sending user does not get an error message and the receiving user receives nothing at all.  Is there any debugging or logging that would help identify the problem?  I've notified Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case, something about the latest build of Messenger stressed our 3 or 4 year old router which was apparently throwing away packets.  But only for the latest Messenger.  We didn't have the problem before.  We replaced our router with a modern router and the problems vanished.

Answer (score 0):

I should add that I've tried two different routers, and even without router (directly connected) so I have no reason to think that it's the internet connection either. Also, I've disabled the firewall and the antivirus and therefore taking that out of the picture.